# Xcode won't recognize my iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

- I am trying to compile my Xcode project on my iPad but I'm getting an error that  says my *iPad can't be recognized*, my device is updated to the latest firmware 9.1 as well as my Xcode compiler. At first I got an error saying *Xcode cannot run using the selected device*, then I unplugged my device and plugged it back in because I was unsure of what to do.
- I also tried testing my project using an iPhone device and the error I got was different. The error said: *No code signing identities found*, I'm not concerned about the iPhone error because my app  was meant for the iPad, I thought i'd point it out because it might give you an idea of why my compilation isn't working.

> I cleaned the project and restarted Xcode to see if that would fix it but it didn't.

- Please help me get by this, Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, the OS version of your device (iPad) is **lower** than **Deployment Target** in **General** tab of the target. Choose another **Deployment Target** which is lower or equal the iPad OS version.

Comment: Thank you for the help! My deployment target wasn't equal to my device.

Comment: It can be lower than OS version of the device

Comment: The OS on the device was higher than the Deployment Target

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch the app on your device manually once and tap on "Trust" on the pop-up before you can run it in the debugger (XCode).